# Python: Import Error

Tags: python, file, directory

Hey Guys I know this has been asked before, and even various times, but I can't really figure out the exact problem with regards to my issue, even after looking at the other import errors.
It's a really basic question, so sorry for that...

I'm writing a program, we'll call it "X.py". I need to import from another file, named graphics.py so my first line of code says:

```
from graphics.py import *
```

I'm pretty sure the rest of my code is right, but when I run the program it gives me the error saying

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/Desktop/X.py", line 1, in <module>
    from graphics import *
ImportError: No module named 'graphics'
```

Now I clearly have this file downloaded and I put them in a folder called Project X, together.

Any idea how I can get this program to see the other file I guess?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: file extension is not included in module statements: `from graphics import *`. Though your error suggests you used the right syntax but python was not able to find graphics because it's not in the [`module search path`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path).

Comment: a note:I hope you're aware that star import are discouraged.

Comment: what's the location of two files?

Comment: x.py is on your desktop, not in a folder called Project X. Is graphics.py on your desktop also?

Answer (score 2):

Drop the .py

Instead, use:

```
  from graphics import *
```

Comment: Looking at the traceback it looks like he used the correct syntax in his program.

Comment: Yeah sorry I didn't format it properly. I did try modifying the name, but the file still isn't being called...

Comment: Where are you getting this graphics.py file? I'll try to replicate on this end.

Comment: Well I download the file from a website and then am essentially trying to use it to build a house using 5 clicks and I need it for colors and what not...

Answer (score 0):

You have to download [this file](http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics.py) and put it in the same folder with your script.
From the docstring:

> INSTALLATION: Put this file somewhere where Python can see it.